# Android parcelable class with object typed properties

Tags: android, kotlin, parcel

So I am currently trying to create an android app capable of displaying calendar bookings.
When I retrieve the bookings I get the following JSON:

```json
{
  "id": "dqflkgjkzmvjdcdfdzs56f4sd7",
  "subject": "Test Meeting",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T14:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-08-02T14:30:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "organiser": "Kermit"
}
```

How do you cast this to a Parcelable class?
I started to make the class like this:

```kt
@Parcelize
class Booking(
    val id: String,
    val subject: String,
    val start: String, /* This */
    val end: String, /* and this has to change to an object*/
    val organiser: String,
): Parcelable
```

Now I still need to find the type for the start and end objects as they have properties themselves and defining it as a separate object seems unnecessary, but that might because I am used to the Angular syntax.

Any ideas on how to cast that JSON data to a Parcelable class?

Comment: @Jagar no I haven't tried it but isn't there a risk by using it? Since it will allow anything to come in as long as it is in JSON format?

Comment: "How do you cast this to a Parcelable class?" -- there is no relationship between JSON and `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you should do with the below way, this would be the better way.

> defining it as a separate object seems unnecessary

At least one object is required to handle the Start & end.

```
@Parcelize
data class Booking(
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: String?,

    @SerializedName("subject")
    var subject: String?,

    @SerializedName("start")
    var start: TimeData?,

    @SerializedName("end")
    var end: TimeData?,

    @SerializedName("organiser")
    var organiser: String?
): Parcelable {

    @Parcelize
    data class TimeData(
        @SerializedName("dateTime")
        var dateTime: String?,

        @SerializedName("timeZone")
        var timeZone: String?
    ): Parcelable

}
```

Use [JSON to Kotlin Class](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) plugin in you android studio, it will help to generate `data class` from the `JSON`